# Get Top N results for each column value

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I've got a table like this:

```
+--------+--------+
|  name  |  kind  |
+--------+--------+
| cat    | animal |
| dog    | animal |
| horse  | animal |
| ant    | animal |
| bird   | animal |
| tree   | plant  |
| grass  | plant  |
| carrot | plant  |
|                 |
|     ... etc.    |
+--------+--------+
```

How can I get Top N items of each **kind**? E.g. N=2:

```
+--------+--------+
|  name  |  kind  |
+--------+--------+
| ant    | animal |
| bird   | animal |
| carrot | plant  |
| grass  | plant  |
+--------+--------+
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [SqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3d6f/5):

```
select name,kind from
(

select Name,Kind,
      @i:=if(@kind=kind,@i+1,1) rn,
      @kind:=kind 
      from t, (select @i:=0,@kind:='') d 
      order by Kind,name
) t1
where t1.rn<=2
     order by Kind,name
```

Comment: This doesn't suite for my approx 1M records. ORDER BY takes a great lot of time.

Comment: I think you can exclude the latest `order by` because the nested query is already sorted so I think MySql will output this query without subquery order change. Also you should index your table using complex Kind and Name index.